# SSRS Combining values within columns

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have a fetchxml report setup to pull data from our CRM instance. Inside Visual Studio 2010 it is laid out as such when it pulls the information

```
job number     new lot         rough start date      city            builder
30774-00c      custom             8/4/2014          city1           builder1
30876-19       465               7/11/2014          city5           builder2
30876-19       466               7/11/2014          city5           builder2
30876-19       467               7/11/2014          city5           builder2
30876-19       489               7/12/2014          city5           builder2 
30856-01        2                 8/26/201          city3           builder5
```

I want to be able to combine the job number and "new lot" where "new roughstartdate" are the same so it would look like

```
job number     new lot         rough start date     city           builder
30774-00c      custom             8/4/2014         city1           builder1
30876-19       465,466,467        7/11/2014        city5           builder2
30876-19       489                7/14/2014        city5           builder2
```

But I just cant seem to figure out the grouping correctly any guidance would be great.

I thought I could do =Join(LookupSet(Fields!jobnumber.Value,Fields!jobnumber.Value,Fields!roughstartdate.Value,"DataSet1"),",")

But that seems to just only show one item when they match and not combine the lots onto a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First group by "rough start date" and then by "Job number" then use below expression in "new lot": 
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!roughstartdate.Value,Fields!roughstartdate.Value,Fields!newlot.Value,"DataSet2"),",")
DataSet2 should be same as DataSet1.

Comment: Thanks I gave this a try and it somewhat worked. But it combined all the LOTS with Matching dates regardless if they are the same job number or not. The sort order would need to be same job number with same date. I tried changing it to =Join(LookupSet(Fields!jobnumber.Value,Fields!jobnumber.Value,Fields!newlot.Value,"DataSet2"),",") Which for the most part worked but say there is 3 lots with the same date it combines them all on the line correctly but repeats 3 times.

Comment: Thanks that just about covers it. Just have an issue with it repeating if say I have job number 555-01 with date 8/27/2014 and lot  1 2 3 and I have job number 555-01 with date 8/30/2014 with lot 4 it puts lots 1 2 3 4 on each one

Comment: Try using this expression..
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!roughstartdate.Value &" "& Fields!jobnumber.Value,Fields!roughstartdate.Value &" "& Fields!jobnumber.Value,Fields!newlot.Value,"DataSet2"),",").

Answer (score 0):

I was just going to comment above but I can't.. So - I think the issue where you have all lots coming back is that the group is just on the Date.

You need to group on Job Number AND Date and then use the Join(LookupSet...

That way you will have groups job number 30876-19 for 7/11/2014 and 30876-19 for 7/12/2014.